# chrome.webRequest requestFilters type doesn't seem to work fine

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm having a strange problem with requestFilters in my chrome extension.

When I try to filter the requests captured by the chrome.webRequest.onCompleted listener, the types filter doesn't seem to work fine. For example :

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(handler, {urls:["http://*/*", "https://*/*"], types:filters}, ["responseHeaders"]);
```

With filters being an array like:

```
var filters = [main_frame, sub_frame, other]
```

I still get a lot of unwanted requests like png/gif files captured. Shouldn't png/gif be part of the image type ? (edit: they seem to fall in the *other* category)

Here is the link to the documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-RequestFilter

Maybe somebody can explain to me why this is happening. Thank you !

Comment: Assuming your handler is `function handler(details)` what is the value of `details.type` for those image urls?

Comment: URL: https://static.login.persona.org/v/ace06c36a7/common/i/button-loader.gif || TYPE: other
URL: https://static.login.persona.org/v/77e5d5d4c5/dialog/i/persona_watermark_sm.png || TYPE: other
URL: https://static.login.persona.org/v/29d9e089cb/dialog/i/persona_watermark_dark_sm.png || TYPE: other
URL: https://static.login.persona.org/v/2056eb3a73/production/de/dialog.js || TYPE: other

Comment: Sorry poorly formated, I hope you can see it. Even on dialog.js the Type is other